# Flutter PaginateFirestore query don't change?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I'm using KrPaginateFirestore with the last version.
I'm trying to change the query to filter my data but it save only the first query data

```
      body: GetBuilder<QuestionController>(
        init: questionContr,
        id: "quizid",
        builder: (controller) {
          return questionContr.filter == "all"
              ? Column(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: KrPaginateFirestore(
                        query: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection("posts")
                            .orderBy("posteddate", descending: true),
                        itemBuilderType: PaginateBuilderType.listView,
                        itemsPerPage: 5,
                        isLive: true,
                        initialLoader: const Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive(),
                        ),
                        bottomLoader: const Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        ),
                        itemBuilder: (context, snapshot, index) {
                          final data = snapshot[index].data()
                              as Map<String, dynamic>;
                          return PostQuestion(
                              snap: data,
                              user: userController.getuser?.uid ??
                                  'default_value');
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              : questionContr.filter == "opened"
                  ? KrPaginateFirestore(
                      query: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection("posts")
                          .where("answered", isEqualTo: false)
                          .orderBy("posteddate", descending: true),
                      itemBuilderType: PaginateBuilderType.listView,
                      itemsPerPage: 5,
                      isLive: true,
                      initialLoader: const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive(),
                      ),
                      bottomLoader: const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      ),
                      itemBuilder: (context, snapshot, index) {
                        final data =
                            snapshot[index].data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                        return PostQuestion(
                            snap: data, user: userController.getuser!.uid);
                      },
                    )
                  : KrPaginateFirestore(
                      query: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection("posts")
                          .where("answered", isEqualTo: true)
                          .orderBy("posteddate", descending: true),
                      itemBuilderType: PaginateBuilderType.listView,
                      itemsPerPage: 5,
                      isLive: true,
                      initialLoader: const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive(),
                      ),
                      bottomLoader: const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      ),
                      itemBuilder: (context, snapshot, index) {
                        final data =
                            snapshot[index].data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                        return PostQuestion(
                            snap: data, user: userController.getuser!.uid);
                      },
                    );
        },
      ),
```

I have three buttons to update to filter my data all questions, Opened questions, and Closed Questions it works well if I move from all to closed or opened and from closed or opened to all but If I choose closed and need to go open it doesn't work!!

```
                    PopupMenuItem(
                        value: 'ALL',
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            print('clicked all');
                            questionContr.setfilter("all");
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                          child: const Row(
                            children: [
                              Icon(
                                Icons.quiz,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                size: 22.0,
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 15.0,
                                ),
                                child: Text(
                                  'All',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 18.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )),
                    PopupMenuItem(
                        value: 'Opened',
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            print('clicked opened');
                            questionContr.setfilter("opened");
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                          child: const Row(
                            children: [
                              Icon(
                                Icons.question_answer,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                size: 22.0,
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 15.0,
                                ),
                                child: Text(
                                  'Opened',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 18.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )),
                    PopupMenuItem(
                        value: 'Closed',
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            print('clicked closed');
                            questionContr.setfilter("closed");
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                          child: const Row(
                            children: [
                              Icon(
                                Icons.close,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                size: 22.0,
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 15.0,
                                ),
                                child: Text(
                                  'Closed',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 18.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )),
```