# flutter firestore pagination using streambuilder?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I'm trying to show only 5 posts per page and every time I'm scrolling shows CircularProgressIndicator and loads the other 5 posts but I got something different the screen shows posts with a circle and all items are shown without getting CircularProgressIndicator while scrolling as you can show at my screenshot that my code

```
  //pagination
  ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
  bool isLoading = false;
  StreamController<List<DocumentSnapshot>> questionController =
      StreamController<List<DocumentSnapshot>>.broadcast();

  Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> get onCurrentUserChanged =>
      questionController.stream;


  List<List<DocumentSnapshot>> allPagedResults = [<DocumentSnapshot>[]];

  static const int questionLimit = 5;
  DocumentSnapshot? _lastDocument;
  bool _hasMoreData = true;

  Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> listenToQuestionsRealTime() {
    _getquestions();
    return questionController.stream;
  }

  void updateQuestions(String filter) {
    // Close the previous stream subscription
    questionController.close();

    // Reset the stream controller
    questionController = StreamController<List<DocumentSnapshot>>.broadcast();

    // Fetch questions with the updated filter
    _getquestions(filter);
  }

  void _getquestions() {
    final Query questionCollectionReference =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts');

    var pagechatQuery = questionCollectionReference
        .orderBy('posteddate', descending: true)
        .limit(questionLimit);

    if (_lastDocument != null) {
      pagechatQuery = pagechatQuery.startAfterDocument(_lastDocument!);
    }

    if (!_hasMoreData) return;
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    var currentRequestIndex = allPagedResults.length;
    pagechatQuery.snapshots().listen(
      (snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
          var generalquestions = snapshot.docs.toList();

          var pageExists = currentRequestIndex < allPagedResults.length;

          if (pageExists) {
            allPagedResults[currentRequestIndex] = generalquestions;
          } else {
            allPagedResults.add(generalquestions);
          }

          var allquestions = allPagedResults.fold<List<DocumentSnapshot>>(
              <DocumentSnapshot>[],
              (initialValue, pageItems) => initialValue..addAll(pageItems));

          questionController.add(allquestions);
          setState(() {
            isLoading = false;
          });

          if (currentRequestIndex == allPagedResults.length - 1) {
            _lastDocument = snapshot.docs.last;
          }

          _hasMoreData = generalquestions.length == questionLimit;
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    updateQuestions(questionContr.filter);
    scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (scrollController.offset >=
              (scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) &&
          !scrollController.position.outOfRange) {
        _getquestions();
      }
    });
  }
```

and that's my body it show at the first time but when I click on closed questions it keeps CircularProgressIndicator on the center screen ?

```
    body: Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: StreamBuilder<List<DocumentSnapshot>>(
            stream: onCurrentUserChanged,
            builder: (ctx, questionSnapshot) {
              if (questionSnapshot.connectionState ==
                  ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              } else if (questionSnapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(
                  child: Text('Error: ${questionSnapshot.error}'),
                );
              } else {
                final questionDocs = questionSnapshot.data ?? [];
                if (questionDocs.isEmpty) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: Text("No Data Available."),
                  );
                } else {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: questionDocs.length +
                        1, // Add 1 for loading indicator
                    itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                      if (index < questionDocs.length) {
                        final questionData = questionDocs[index].data()
                            as Map<String, dynamic>;
                        return PostQuestion(
                          snap: questionData,
                          user: userController.getuser?.uid,
                        );
                      } else {
                        // Reached end of the list, show loading indicator
                        return const SizedBox();
                      }
                    },
                    controller: scrollController,
                  );
                }
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
        isLoading
            ? const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              )
            : Container()
      ],
    ),
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: `stream: listenToQuestionsRealTime(),` Do not build the stream in the stream: parameter of the StreamBuilder.  See this video for details: https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I will edit my question can you please check it ?

Comment: if I can help, I use this package: https://github.com/waqadArshad/paginate_firestore

Comment: @Jordaninho If I need to make search function how can I make it with that package?

Comment: I use a Firestore query via the query property.

Comment: @Jordaninho yeh thanks I got what you mean, But I have only 1 question left please when I click into closed questions it works but when I click on open don't work I have to click all again then chose open why that?

Comment: @Jordaninho can you please check this code for me please sir? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78035377/flutter-paginatefirestore-query-dont-change